# How can I get PDF Reports in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, pdf-generation

I have my final project and it is in `MVC 4` and `SQL` . All I need to know is , how could I get simple and fast `PDF` reports in `MVC`.

I have tried `Razor` PDF but it does not support `CSS` or it is difficult to use (for me).

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use jspdf library which takes care of CSS and all the styling. https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF